# how to call and add conditions in procedures while calling from Ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a report using Ireport 4.5 but report is running very slow I think just because of multiple UNION and JOINS.

I am copying a simple query for testing purpose:-

```
   SELECT b.Project_Id,
       b.Project_Manager,
       b.project_title,
       b.Project_location,
       b.Project_Level,
      SUM(COALESCE(b.Project_Budget, 0)) Projected,
      SUM(COALESCE(c.Accounting, 0)) Actual
   FROM t_authorized_budget a, t_project_c b,t_project_allocation c
   WHERE a.Project_Id = b.Project_Id and b.project_id=c.`Key` 
        and a.Project_Id = c.`Key`
        and $X{IN,b.project_location,p_project_location}
        and $X{IN,b.project_manager,p_project_manager}
        and $X{IN,b.project_id,p_project_id};
```

So I created a procedure CALL GetAllcompo() using this query but without

```
        $X{IN,b.project_location,p_project_location}
        and $X{IN,b.project_manager,p_project_manager}
        and $X{IN,b.project_id,p_project_id};
```

Now i am trying to add these conditions in procedure while calling from Ireport.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the procedure? I do this by adding another parameter. First, prompt the user to define what type of WHERE clause you're using:

```
$P{PROJECT_PROMPT}
```

And then create a second parameter ($P{PROJECT_SQL_DEF}) with a default expression that defines your WHERE clause:

```
 $P{PROJECT_PROMPT} == 'SHORT' ? 
      " ' a.Project_Id = b.Project_Id 
      and b.project_id=c.Key 
      and a.Project_Id = c.Key '" : 

      " ' a.Project_Id = b.Project_Id and b.project_id=c.`Key` 
      and a.Project_Id = c.`Key`
      and $X{IN,b.project_location,p_project_location}
      and $X{IN,b.project_manager,p_project_manager}
      and $X{IN,b.project_id,p_project_id} ' "
```

In your query:

```
 SELECT b.Project_Id,
   b.Project_Manager,
   b.project_title,
   b.Project_location,
   b.Project_Level,
  SUM(COALESCE(b.Project_Budget, 0)) Projected,
  SUM(COALESCE(c.Accounting, 0)) Actual
FROM t_authorized_budget a, t_project_c b,t_project_allocation c
WHERE $P!{PROJECT_SQL_DEF}
```

Comment: Another thought -- if you pass a null to $X{... it is equal to 1=1. So what happens if you use the full WHERE clause, and just don't pass parameters to the $X{... ?

Comment: I think if we don't pass any parameter to the $X{} means all values without any where condition.What do you think?

Comment: True, it would be just like "and $X{IN, b.project_location, p_project_location}" gets replaced with "and 1=1". It would give you all b.project_location values.